Is it possible to make Rails.logger output to delayed_job.log?
I have some code that runs both in the main process and in an ActiveJob. It uses Rails.logger.info. When the code runs in delayed_job, I want it to log to the delayed_job.log file instead of the main log file. Is this possible?
